# Maven Cargo Plugin: goal "undeploy" fails despite watchdog

Tags: maven, plugins, jboss7.x, watchdog, cargo

I use Cargo to deploy a maven generated war file to a remote JBoss Server that is already running. Normally that works fine. Cargo is configured to undeploy in mavne's pre-clean-Phase and to deploy in maven's install-phase. That means, if there's an error e.g. in the compile-phase, there will be no deployment.
To handle this, I'm using cargo's watchdog. So in the next maven-cycle, when there's no deployable to undeploy, the watchdog should recognize there's nothing to undeploy and corgo should not throw an failure. According to [this](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container) page, that's exactly what the Watchdog is made for (scroll down to the bottom).

But guess what happend? Cargo generates a build-Failure.

I'm pretty sure, the watchdog itself is working properly, because when I had another issue with the undeployer a few month ago (caused by firewall-settings), the watchdog realised, the undeployment didn't succeed.

I didn't find anything helpful on stackoverflow nor on the [cargo-jira-page](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-1100?jql=project%20=%20CARGO%20AND%20text%20~%20%22watchdog%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC). I' didn't saw the option to add a ticket for cargo. Mybe someone knows this behaviour and how to fix it.

My pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
            <container>
                <timeout>300000</timeout>
                <containerId>jboss71x</containerId>
                <type>remote</type>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.hostname><myHost></cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.jboss.management-native.port>9999</cargo.jboss.management-native.port>
                    <cargo.remote.username><myUsername></cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password><myPassword></cargo.remote.password>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <deployer>
                <type>remote</type>
            </deployer>
            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <groupId><myGroupId></groupId>
                    <artifactId><myArtifactId></artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <properties>
                        <context><myContext></context>
                    </properties>
                    <location>${project.build.directory}\${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</location>
                    <pingURL><myPingUrl></pingURL>
                    <pingTimeout>60000</pingTimeout>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>undeploy</id>
                <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>undeploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>deploy</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: As a Workaround I'm using 'redeploy' in maven's install-Phase, but I'm not totally happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but there is a [`org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) though that you could use.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried this plugin, but didn't liked it...actually I forget why I didn't liked it. Maybe I should re-evaluate this plugin.

Comment: And if you do please give feedback on why you didn't like it so we can fix it :)

Comment: Just as a feedback: I didn't had time to reevaluate the jboss-plugin. My Workaround is still the working solution.